# Как добавить свою функцию для ПКМ под caja в linux?

Tags: linux, caja

Нашёл такую [статью](http://www.ethanjoachimeldridge.info/tech-blog/caja-exifstrip-context-action), где говорится что для создания своей функции нужно перейти в папку **scripts** - `/.config/caja/scripts` и создать там sh скрипт с таким содержимым, и после чего сделать этот файл запускаемым:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
    mimetype $f | grep "image" && exiftool -all= $f
done
```

Собственно вопрос,как изменить его под `srm` программу ?

Скрипт будет таким ?:

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in $CAJA_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS
do
    srm $f 
done
```

**Обновление вопроса**

Если сделать как описано выше, то появится пункт scripts и в нём наше действие (как в Create Document), а как сделать как Create Folder с добавлением картинки ? :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]